# Why is the JSeparator not displayed as a horizontal line?

Tags: jseparator

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("INFO");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("TEXT");

panel.add(label1);
panel.add(new JSeparator());
panel.add(label2);
```

No horizontal line is displayed. Any help?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html). maybe try `panel.addSeparator()`. Don't know why yours isn't working though

Comment: Nope,it doesnt work..

Comment: How about [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/556868/GUI/java/separator-visible) one? Ok, now I am just guessing.

Comment: yeah tried that too,was looking over google before posting here,no good results